# Fail to get a range of dates by (Date.today..Date.new(2012, 4, 1)).select

Tags: ruby, range

I just encountered a weird behavious of getting a range of dates in Ruby.

`(Date.new(2012, 4, 1)..Date.today).select { |d| p d }` works

`(Date.today..Date.new(2012, 4, 1)).select { |d| p d }` fails.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range can't go backwards, hence it returns an empty array.